# Is there any way to get Client Id and Secret of UPS without providing payment information

Tags: sandbox, ups

We’re creating a UPS connector and wanted to test UPS APIs.
Is there a way to get ClientID and secrets without payment details or providing test credit card details to explore sandbox APIs.